# Sharing Objects from Facebook Newsfeed to Facebook Groups Inoperative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

FB Server throws a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" when attempting to share any object from the Newsfeed to any Group from selection list. 
Group selection dropdown list fails to appear. Typeahead autocomplete fails. 
However, sharing to wall, friends, or pages other than Groups works fine from the selection list. 
No 'feature disabled' warnings or notices prior to this. 
Overrun of users in Help section of Facebook waiting for years to have this sharing issue remedied. 
Cleared cache, cookies, etc, refreshed, restarted- issue still exists. 
Issue manifests regardless of browser used- IE, Chrome, Firefox. 
Other users/accounts on the same computer station do not manifest this issue. 
Using clean computer with Windows 8.1. 
This sharing issue previously did not exist on this account a month ago and functioned normally. 
A user suggested that the number of Groups may affect the performance of the database query in the typeahead function disabling the drop down list? Running out of clues..

Net line that fails with 500 error:
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?viewer=100000926079301&filter[0]=group&request_id=0.014976577367633581&__user=000000xxxxxxxxx&__a=1&__dyn=7n8ahyngCBynzpQ9UoHFaeFDzECiq78hACF3qGEVFLFwxBxCbzESu49UJ6K4bBxi8w&__req=b&__rev=1406248

screen shot post denied

Comment: Go file a bug under https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: i did- tried to but they required too many details that i don't know to complete their form- Thanks!